# Bayes' theorem - Updating Probabilities

Tags: probability

Thanks for reading this. I'll caution that it's quite the wall of text, but this is for my stochastic processes course.

Due to recent news of horse meat in frozen food products, ABC Meat Distributors has hired two special investigators, Brody and Carrie, to examine their meat products. Brody will inspect beef products, while Carrie will inspect pork products. The company believes that each beef product has a 10% chance of being contaminated with horse meat and each pork product has a 15% chance of being contaminated. Assume all products are independent of each other. The time it takes Brody and Carrie to inspect a single product is randomly distributed, following an exponential distribution with an average of 60 minutes and 45 minutes, respectively.

.. (There were 4 questions here which I answered based on the above information, but I'm pretty sure they weren't relevant to the the bottom one which is the one I'm having difficulty with) ..

At the start of the day, Brody did not believe the company’s estimate of the percentage of contaminated beef products. Instead, he believed that with probability 0.4 the percentage of contaminated beef products is 10% and with probability 0.6 the percentage of contaminated beef products is 20%. At the end of the day, Brody found that 3 out of the 10 beef products he inspected were contaminated.

Use Bayes' rule to update Brody's belief about the probability that 20% of the beef products are contaminated.

Attempt: Let A be the event that he believes that 20% of beef products are contaminated. Let B be the event that he found 3 out of the 10 beef products to be contaminated

P(A | B) = P(B | A) P (A) / P(B)

I think P(B | A) would be something like ${10 \choose 3} * 0.2^3 * 0.8^7$. Again I'm not entirely sure

I know P(A) to be .6, but I'm struggling to get P(B|A) and P(B). (I am not sure if this is even right). And I'm pretty sure the probability increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to be precise about the random variables and events of interest.

Let $X$ be the random number of contaminated beef products found in the sample of $n = 10$ investigated items.  Then $$X \mid \Theta \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 10, p = \Theta),$$ where $\Theta$ is itself a random variable that characterizes the probability that a single item chosen at random is found to be contaminated.  The prior probability distribution on $\Theta$ is discrete:  $$\Pr[\Theta = \theta] = \begin{cases} 0.4, & \theta = 0.1 \\ 0.6, & \theta = 0.2. \end{cases}$$  The desired quantity of interest is $$\Pr[\Theta = 0.2 \mid X = 3],$$ the **posterior** probability that $\Theta = 0.2$ given that the data $X = 3$ was observed.  By Bayes' theorem, we have $$\Pr[\Theta = 0.2 \mid X = 3] = \frac{\Pr[X = 3 \mid \Theta = 0.2] \Pr[\Theta = 0.2]}{\Pr[X = 3]}.$$  The numerator is easily computed from the information given thus far.  However, the denominator is not yet clear, since we don't have the **unconditional** or **marginal** probability distribution of $X$.  To this end, we use the law of total probability:  $$\Pr[X = x] = \Pr[X = x \mid \Theta = 0.1]\Pr[\Theta = 0.1] + \Pr[X = x \mid \Theta = 0.2]\Pr[\Theta = 0.2].$$  This is simply a special case of conditioning $X$ on the random variable $\Theta$, since the permissible prior values of $\Theta$ are understood to be only $\Theta \in \{0.1, 0.2\}$.  So now we have all the information we need:  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[X = 3 \mid \Theta = 0.1] &= \binom{10}{3} (0.1)^3 (0.9)^7, \\ \Pr[X = 3 \mid \Theta = 0.2] &= \binom{10}{3} (0.2)^3 (0.8)^7, \end{align*}$$ so the desired posterior probability is (note the cancellation of the binomial coefficients) $$\Pr[\Theta = 0.2 \mid X = 3] = \frac{(0.2)^3 (0.8)^7 (0.6)}{(0.1)^3 (0.9)^7 (0.4) + (0.2)^3 (0.8)^7 (0.6)} = \ldots.$$

---

As an additional exercise, I strongly recommend that you generalize this problem to the cases where Brody observed $X = x$ contaminated products (rather than $3$).  What is the resulting posterior distribution of $\Theta$?  It will be a function of $x$, the number of contaminated items found in the sample.

Comment: Thanks, very clear explaination.